# Convert TypeOrm entities to react friendly Typescript DTO

Tags: reactjs, typescript, shared-libraries, typeorm, monorepo

I have around 200 typeOrm entities that I woul dlike to refer into my Typescript React code.

It's a monorepo project like:

-|-back
|-shared
|-front

my entities are like this:

```
import {Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToOne} from "typeorm";
import {childRelationOptions, parentEagerRelationOptions} from "../typeorm-helper/src";
import {Nationality} from "./cold-data/nationality.entity";
import {Situation} from "./cold-data/situation.entity";
import {Document} from "./document.entity";
import {
    IsDate,
    IsMobilePhone,
    IsNotEmpty,
    IsNotEmptyObject,
    IsOptional,
    IsString,
    Matches,
    ValidateIf,
    ValidateNested
} from "class-validator";
import {ExportFor} from "../export/src";
import {UserRoleEnum} from "./User-role.enum";
import {VersionedBaseWithId} from "./versioned-base-with-id.entity";
import {CandidateFile} from "./candidate-file.entity";
import {DocumentTypeEnum} from "./cold-data/document-type.entity";
import {alwaysValidate, validateForSave, validateForSubmit} from "../class-validator-test-helper/src";
import {Empty, Fake, getEmpty, getFake} from "../context";
/**
 * Contains all candidate personal data
 */
import * as faker from "faker";

@Entity()
export class Profile extends VersionedBaseWithId {

    @OneToOne(() => CandidateFile, (e: CandidateFile) => e.profile, childRelationOptions)
    @JoinColumn()
    public candidateFile: CandidateFile
    // noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
    @Fake((context) => {
        const d: Document = context.japd || getFake(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.JAPD
        return d
    })
    @Empty((context) => {
        const d: Document = getEmpty(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.JAPD
        return d
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateIf(o => o.nationality?.name === "Française", validateForSubmit)
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(type => Document, parentEagerRelationOptions)
    public JAPDDocument: Document

    @Fake(faker.random.boolean)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    funded: boolean
    @Fake(faker.random.boolean)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    thirdPartyTime: boolean
    @Fake(faker.address.streetAddress)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @IsString(alwaysValidate)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    address1: string
    @Fake(faker.address.streetAddress)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(alwaysValidate)
    @IsString({always: true})
    @Column({nullable: true})
    address2: string
    @Fake(faker.address.zipCode, '#####')
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @Matches(/^[0-9\- a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]{0}$/, {always: true})
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    zipCode: string
    @Fake(faker.address.city)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsString(alwaysValidate)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    city: string
    @Fake(faker.phone.phoneNumber, '065######')
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsMobilePhone(undefined, undefined, {always: true})
    @Column({nullable: true})
    phone: string
    @Fake(faker.date.past, 10, new Date(2001, 0, 1))
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsDate({always: true})
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    birthDate: Date
    @Fake(faker.address.city)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @IsString({always: true})
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @IsNotEmpty(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(alwaysValidate)
    @Column({nullable: true})
    birthPlace: string
    @Fake((context) => {
        return context.nationality
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateNested()
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(() => Nationality, {cascade: false})
    nationality: Nationality
    @Fake((context) => {
        return context.situation
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(() => Situation, {cascade: false})
    situation: Situation
    @Fake((context) => {
        const d: Document = context.avatarDocument || getFake(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.AVATAR
        return d
    })
    @Empty((context) => {
        const d: Document = getEmpty(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.AVATAR
        return d
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(() => Document, parentEagerRelationOptions)
    avatarDocument: Document

    @Fake((context) => {
        const d: Document = context.cv || getFake(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.CV
        return d
    })
    @Empty((context) => {
        const d: Document = getEmpty(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.CV
        return d
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(() => Document, parentEagerRelationOptions)
    cvDocument: Document
// noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
    @Fake((context) => {
        const d: Document = context.thirdPartyTimeDocument || getFake(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.THIRD_PARTY_TIME
        return d
    })
    @Empty((context) => {
        const d: Document = getEmpty(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.THIRD_PARTY_TIME
        return d
    })
    @ManyToOne(type => Document, parentEagerRelationOptions)
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateIf((o: Profile) => o.thirdPartyTime, validateForSubmit)
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    thirdPartyTimeDocument: Document

    @Fake((context) => {
        const d: Document = context.idCardDocument || getFake(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.ID_CARD
        return d
    })
    @Empty((context) => {
        const d: Document = getEmpty(new Document(), context)
        d.type.id = DocumentTypeEnum.ID_CARD
        return d
    })
    @ExportFor([UserRoleEnum.SECRETARY])
    @ValidateNested(alwaysValidate)
    @IsNotEmptyObject(validateForSubmit)
    @IsOptional(validateForSave)
    @ManyToOne(() => Document, parentEagerRelationOptions)
    idCardDocument: Document

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I would like to generate a DTO for each entities, the goal might be to have something like the .d.ts file:

```
import { Nationality } from "./cold-data/nationality.entity";
import { Situation } from "./cold-data/situation.entity";
import { Document } from "./document.entity";
import { VersionedBaseWithId } from "./versioned-base-with-id.entity";
import { CandidateFile } from "./candidate-file.entity";
export declare class Profile extends VersionedBaseWithId {
    candidateFile: CandidateFile;
    JAPDDocument: Document;
    funded: boolean;
    thirdPartyTime: boolean;
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    zipCode: string;
    city: string;
    phone: string;
    birthDate: Date;
    birthPlace: string;
    nationality: Nationality;
    situation: Situation;
    avatarDocument: Document;
    cvDocument: Document;
    thirdPartyTimeDocument: Document;
    idCardDocument: Document;
    constructor();
}
```

How do you do to share code without decorator with your react app?

Answer (score 0):

I tried that:

```
"generate:dto": "yarn workspace back build && rm -rf dto && find ../back/dist/ -name '*.entity.d.ts' | cpio -pdm  . | mv back/dist dto",
```

It generated a folder with all d.ts file